# Angular module has no exported member 'ButtonFillMode'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I am getting error saying **'"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons"' has no exported member 'ButtonFillMode'.** while using kendo Editor toolbar module. I have install all the dependencies for EditorModule libraries. Even I am getting the same error. the link which I am referring to use editor toolbar in angular is https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/editor/tools/

Belows are the error which I am getting while building my Angular project.

[image]

I am using Angular 12 with Kendo UI. Also I'm trying use kendo Editor Toolbar libraries.

please let me know if you have faced this kinds of error and if you have resolved it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest removing the dependencies and installing them again. My guess is that kendo-angular-toolbar is in a newer version than kendo-angular-buttons so they are incompatible

Comment: I had reinstalled it. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Check what versions are on your package lock. Are any of those dependencies new?

Comment: I have checked it. Is there any other reason to get this error?

Comment: What are the versions on package.json? I will try to reproduce it

Comment: But in any case, since this is a paid lib, they probably have some kind of support

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the options are explicitly defined in Kendo's library. If you look at the underlying JavaScript (specifically kendo-angular-buttons/dist/cdn/main.js), the `getStylingClasses` method does the following:

```js
t.getStylingClasses = function(e, n, i, o) {
  switch (n) {
    case "size":
      return {
        toRemove: "k-" + e + "-" + t.SIZES[i], toAdd: o ? "k-" + e + "-" + t.SIZES[o] : null
      };
    case "rounded":
      return {
        toRemove: "k-rounded-" + a[i], toAdd: o ? "k-rounded-" + a[o] : null
      };
    case "fillMode":
    case "shape":
      return {
        toRemove: "k-" + e + "-" + i, toAdd: o ? "k-" + e + "-" + o : null
      }
  }
}
```

Theoretically you can set the `fillMode` to a bad value (like foo), all it does is add the following classes:

```css
.k-button-foo-base, .k-button-foo
```

I think your best option would be to simply define the values as an exportable enum:

```typescript
export enum ButtonFillMode {
  Solid = 'solid',
  Flat = 'flat',
  Outline = 'outline',
  Clear = 'clear',
  Link = 'link',
}
```